# Dual Boot-Ubuntu along with Win 7, ubuntu not detecting the partitions on HDD on which Win 7 is currently exist as sole OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I recently (19.03.2015) purchased Dell Insp 15 3543 (Ubuntu OS). As I wanted to Dual Boot Ubuntu along with Windows 7, I did not complete the Ubuntu installation (Pre-provided with Laptop, & started Installing windows 7 from Installation CD.  While, at the option of selecting where to install the Win 7 OS, I deleted all partitions:
A. Partition 0 OEM Recov[300 MB], 
B. Partition 1 [3-4 GB] probably where the Ubuntu OS /Ubuntu Setup was on and 
C. Partition 2 Free/Unallocated Space [Rest of HDD])

Now everything worked correctly until just after completing the installation I discovered I accidentally deleted OEM Recv Partition also.

And afterwords while I was Installing Ubuntu from USB (bootable drive), the Ubuntu installation did not detected the Windows 7, (even though if I normally boot /Switch On my laptop, laptop was normally and correctly loading Win 7 and also showing C Drive (OS) and other drives (that I created, just after Win 7 installation was complete.)

Now my problem is

1. Can I get the OEM Recovery partition back? does this mean that I have to sent this laptop to the service centre of Dell OR Dell will provide some CD that will do the work.
2. Does deletion of OEM Recovery Partition is causing the problem of not showing the Win 7 as OS while installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Please help me out here, I really want both systems on my laptop. If further info needed, do tell me !

Note: --My laptop came with Ubuntu 14.04 Pre-Installation Setup. So is OEM deletion is really the problem?
***I just checked my partition is not Dynamic its basic only.***

**Also the Laptop was on UEFI mode (from where the boot option was Ubuntu) & not on Legacy. B4 installing Win 7 I changed this to Legacy**

Comment: 1) Yes, and maybe. you may be able to recover those partitions using testdisk but it's unlikely as you've probably overwritten all that in your attempt to install Windows 7 where you amde the major mistake of deleting all partitions prior to installation.  2) No. NOTE: Requests regarding Windows software are extremely likely to be considered off-topic here and will likely be closed as such. I recommend [edit]ing your question to fit the parameters here: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK! thanks, but see i did not know that and secondly then what is the workaround if i only have Windows OS as of now! & i dont know but is there any software that works from ubuntu bootable usb and does the same work ? Also note that this is brand new laptop, there was nothing on it, except per-installation setup of ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Also can can i use gparted or fixparts ?? how to use the same

Comment: Workaround: Boot from Ubuntu installation media you have on USB, choose try Ubuntu and then install Ubuntu and choose to run alongside Windows Your OEM recovery partition will still be gone but I doubt you'll need it since it came with Ubuntu and you have 14.04 on USB. did you happen to convert your Windows partitions to Dynamic? This may be one of your actual problems.

Comment: [edit] your question to fit the parameters here: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but i am new here, Please, can u or anyone suggest some good title to do that !!

Comment: backto your soln(elder greek) :I did not get what do you mean by Dynamic partition. How do i check if my partition is dynamic or not, Also if needed is there anything(log) that will tell you guys what is my current partition is like and its properties?

Comment: In Windows disk management the partitions will be labled either Basic or Dynamic http://www.learn44.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Dynamic-Disks-Microsoft-Disk-Management-Console-www.learn44.com_.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***

(Basically it was GPT data left of the [then] existing Pre-Installation Setup Files of Ubuntu that the Laptop came up with, following instructions helped to clear those [1st two Links]. Then Installed Ubuntu (correctly shown the existing partitions; installed on partition created from free space), then just to make sure Windows 7 boots properly installed-updated-repaired the Grub [3rd Link]

[No PARTITIONs found while installing, dual-boot Win8/Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486556/no-partitions-found-while-installing-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-14-04)

[GPT partition table warning message during install of ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249642/gpt-partition-table-warning-message-during-install-of-ubuntu)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair

Also interesting to note that OEM Deletion was not problem. (Even though its mistake & a horrible one for Systems with Pre Installed/ Setups of OS other that Open Source) But like @Elder Greek said, my laptop came with Ubuntu & not Windows, so i was saved.
**The problem was deletion of a partition where the Ubuntu setup file were existing**, that left some GPT data on HDD even after deletion.

PS: Thanks to all those who tried to ans to my question without a fuss !! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

1st) Get your Windows 7 SP1 install media and delete EVERYTHING you have on your PC, all partitions and everything.

Once it has succesfully installed go to the Ubuntu website and download Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits. Download also Universal USB installer and create a bootable USB.

Shutdown your PC.

2nd) Start your PC again and boot from the USB you have just created with Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits. When you are installing it choose to install with Windows 7, and you will now have your PC as you wanted, detecting both partitions and working correctly.

PS: 1st install Windows 2nd Ubuntu. :)

Comment: Yes, i was doing that only !! only thing is that the laptop came with per-installation setup of Ubuntu 14.04. I did not complete the installation and gone straight to Install Win 7 64bit ultimate, but in that rush i accidentally deleted all partitions that was on laptop including OEM Recovery Partition. Now currently my laptop have Win 7 64 bit perfectly working and showing both drives C:OS, and E:Other partition created & [if i gone to partition table of Win 7- 179gb of unallocated space] Total HDD Size 931.5GB